Custom Picker ID
I'm trying to setup a picker with dynamic contents and a custom ID, but i'm running into issues getting this working. I'm probably going about this totally wrong.
I'm getting information from a my website using the below code.
function unnamedDecks($pdo) {
$sql = "SELECT u.ID, u.description, c.name
FROM deck_unnamed AS u
LEFT JOIN deck_categories AS c ON c.ID = u.category
WHERE deck IS NULL;";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute();
if($q->errorCode() != 0) {
   $errors = $q->errorInfo();
     echo($errors[2]);
}
foreach ($q->fetchAll() as $row) {
  $unnamed[] = array('ID' => $row['ID'], 'name' => $row['name'], 'description' => $row['description']);
}

$arr = array(
             "decks" => (isset($unnamed)) ? $unnamed : "0",
             );

echo json_encode($arr);
}

An example of the response from the function is

{"decks":[{"ID":"69","name":"???","description":"???"},{"ID":"X1","name":"???","description":"???"}]}

Then in the app processing it using
func getUnnamedDecksList() async -> UnnamedDeckList? {
    let downloadTask = Task { () -> UnnamedDeckList in
        let url : String = "****"
        
        var components = URLComponents(string: url)!
        components.queryItems = [
            URLQueryItem(name: "action", value: "unnamedDecks")
        ]
        components.percentEncodedQuery = components.percentEncodedQuery?.replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "%2B")
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: components.url!)
        let result = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
        let jsonData = result.data(using: .utf8)!
        let dataRes: UnnamedDeckList = try! JSONDecoder().decode(UnnamedDeckList.self, from: jsonData)
        return dataRes
    }
    let result = await downloadTask.result
    do {
        let categories = try result.get()
        return categories
    } catch {
        print("Unknown error.")
    }
    return nil
}

The setup of the UnnamedDeckList & related class
struct UnnamedDeck : Decodable {
    let name : String
    let ID : String
    let description : String
}

struct UnnamedDeckList : Decodable {
    let decks : [UnnamedDeck]
}

Then trying to display with a picker, where UnnamedDeck.name is what's shown, and ID is it's ID, but this is where I'm getting stuck.
I can get the picker to show what I want by doing the below, but I can't get the ID using it.
let catsArray = getCategoryList()
        Picker("", selection: $category) {
            ForEach(catsArray, id: \.self) {
                Text($0)
            }
        }


Can you show what is getCategoryList() and how you declare its elements, also show how you declare
category.  These should be of the same type.
In your Picker, you should make  the elements of your catsArray Identifiable, then use
ForEach(catsArray){ item in ...}. You then have to add Text(item).tag(item) and
make sure the tag item is of the same type as your category.

An alternative to my comment, you could try this approach, declare
@State private var category: String = "" // <--- here, same type as `id`

and use,
 struct UnnamedDeck: Identifiable, Decodable { // <--- here
     let id: String  // <--- here
     let name : String
     let description : String
     
     enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
         case id = "ID"  // <--- here
         case name, description
     }
 }



 let catsArray = getCategoryList()  // assuming array of UnnamedDeck types
 
 Picker("", selection: $category) {
     ForEach(catsArray) {
         Text($0.name)
     }
 }

category has the selected String ID (of property id) for you to use.

did my answer not work for you?
